# Convert screen size from pixel to scene size in meter

Tags: view, screen, pixel, scene, meter

I have a problem to obtain the real value of a scene. I have a camera with 752x480 screen type and I want to measure in meters the dimension of the scene that can be taken by this camera. I know also the focal length and also the distance to this scene.
My idea is: we know the dimension of frustum:

```
- width: 480 px;
- height: 752 px;
- focal length: 9 mm (aprox. 34 px);
- distance to the scene from screen: 20 m;
```

Using correspondence theory I have obtained:

```
480/f (px) =w(m)/d(m)
d(m)=(480px * 20m)/(34px)=282m
```

Am I right?